# How to call only a key or a value from a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I call only a key or value from a hash? In the following example how could I get the the code to return

> cat's are lazy
>
> dog's are fun
>
> hippo's are big

Any idea??

```
['cat' => 'lazy', 'dog' => 'fun', 'hippo' => 'big'].each do |animal|
    template = ERB.new "#{animal}'s are #{animal}"
    puts template.result(binding)
end
```

Comment: Why don't you make it a hash `{'cat' => 'lazy', 'dog' => 'fun', 'hippo' => 'big'}`?

Comment: Why you were using `ERB`, if you not need it ?

Comment: going through tutorials that used it, learning/practicing at this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the Block of a Hash with 2 variables, for a `key` and a `value`. Also, keep in mind you actually have an Array with 1 Hash inside (so your `animal` variable is the entire Hash). Better to define it as a Hash.

```
hash = {
  'cat' => 'lazy',
  'dog' => 'fun',
  'hippo' => 'big'
}

hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key} = #{value}"  
end

# Output:
# cat = lazy
# dog = fun
# hippo = big
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to use `Hash` instead of an `Array` :

```
{'cat' => 'lazy', 'dog' => 'fun', 'hippo' => 'big'}.each do |animal, character|
    template = ERB.new "#{animal}'s are #{character}"
    puts template.result(binding)
end
```

Gives

```
cat's are lazy
dog's are fun
hippo's are big
```

Comment: Yes,,, That's the reason. It should be a `Hash`. I couldn't answer. I didn't see also, OP used it as `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, using the original array that the OP put

```
animal_printer = -> hash { puts "#{hash.first}'s are #{hash.last}" }
['cat' => 'lazy', 'dog' => 'fun', 'hippo' => 'big'].first.each(&animal_printer)
```

Prints the asked result by the OP

```
cat's are lazy
dog's are fun
hippo's are big
```